# Explanation for apparent fires visible from plane over Iran

Tags: air-travel, iran

On 29 August 2014, I was on flight EK038 to Dubai. When the plane was passing over a mountainous region of Iran at cruising altitude (on the early morning of the 30th), I looked out the window and could spot many yellow lights, that looked quite large. The brightness, apparent size and colour of the lights suggests to me that they were fires, perhaps from oil fields or something? (The lights were individual spots)

Comment: EK038. I noticed it avoided Ukraine and Iraq.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit, can you positively identify for us your exact flight including airline and date? We can look up the exact flight path to see where you overflew, which might help make this answerable.

Comment: Emirates EK038 Departure 21:00 29/08/14

Comment: I found your question tho questioning the same sight. It is wery interesting becouse you seen it 8 years ago, and it's stil the same. looks like hudge cer sized firepits randomly dropped each other about 500-1000m. Although we never get the right answer, I'm happy to found that someone interested too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an Iranian I'd say most probable explanation is that you've seen gas flares of some oil refineries.